# ARM - Why ASM code has dummy instructions?

Tags: assembly, arm

Seen this portion of code in a firmware :

```
(1)LDR             R0, =0x68010000
(2)ADD             R1, R0, #0x68
(3)MOV             R2, #0xFFFFFFFF
(4)STR             R2, [R1]
```

Well,

A) first, why 2 operations (1) and (2) to store value #68010068 in R1 ?

B) secondly, on line (4), store R1 pointed address in R2, so what's the purpose of (3) ?

regards

Comment: A) who knows, maybe `R0` is used later as well. B) that instruction writes `R2` into memory, so obviously `R2` has to be set.

Comment: ok for A), but I don't understand your reply for B. (3) seem useless, no ? if, I'm right (3) set R2= 0xffffffff and (4) set R2=content pointed by R1.

Comment: Jester, ok for B), I was wrong on STR syntax.

Comment: GSG, thanks, so It has sense

Comment: the reason for 2 is most likely because r0 is going to be used again in code you did not show.  although it could have used str r2,[r0,#0x68] if this is arm, if thumb then probably not and this code is as good as it gets.

Comment: afaik - due to limited space in the opcodes - it's not possible to load a constant #68010068 into an ARM register, using in one single instruction. LDR uses an encoding like LDR '0x6801<<16' (i don't recall the limits) and then has to add the missing offset ( this is called 'literal' if i remember correctly)